# error when using Union clause postgresql 9.5

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_locations(
    location_word varchar(50)
    ) 
RETURNS TABLE
(
    country varchar(50),
    city varchar(50)
)
AS $$
DECLARE
location_word_ varchar(50);
BEGIN
location_word_:=concat(location_word, '%');
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format('   (SELECT c.country, ''::varchar(50) as city FROM webuser.country c 
                                    WHERE lower(c.country)  LIKE %L  LIMIT 1)
                                UNION
                                (SELECT c.country,ci.city FROM webuser.country c
                                    JOIN webuser.city ci ON c.country_id=ci.country_id
                                    WHERE lower(ci.city) LIKE %L LIMIT 4)', 
                                    location_word_,
                                    location_word_ )    ;

END
$$ language PLPGSQL STABLE;
```

**This is the error that i get ;**

- ERROR:  syntax error at or near "%"
- LINE 2:          WHERE lower(c.country)  LIKE 'a%'  LIMIT 1)

Why do i get this error?

**EDIT**

When I just replaced `''::varchar(50)` with `''''::varchar(50)` it worked!

Comment: `%L` is a typo for what should be `'%L'`, in quotes.  There may be other problems too, but this should fix the error you reported.

Comment: Why a PL/pgSQL function? Why dynamic SQL? This can be done a lot simpler with a plain SQL function and without dynamic SQL. http://dpaste.com/1A96R5C

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i don't know, i generally use this way...well if i can not fix this, i will use your code...

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen i am sorry this didnt work...

Answer (score 1):

Try next corrected function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_locations(
    location_word varchar(50)
    ) 
RETURNS TABLE
(
    country varchar(50),
    city varchar(50)
)
AS $$
DECLARE
location_word_ varchar(50);
BEGIN
location_word_:=concat(location_word, '%');
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format('   (SELECT c.country, ''''::varchar(50) as city FROM webuser.country c 
                                    WHERE c.country ILIKE ''%L'' LIMIT 1)
                                UNION
                                (SELECT c.country,ci.city FROM webuser.country c
                                    JOIN webuser.city ci ON c.country_id=ci.country_id
                                    WHERE ci.city ILIKE ''%L'' LIMIT 4)', 
                                    location_word_,
                                    location_word_ )    ;

END
$$ language PLPGSQL STABLE;
```

Comment: The placeholder `%L` **will** add single quotes as needed. Do **not** include them in the format string `''%L''` will generate additional single quotes at runtime. The culprit is the `''::varchar(50)` which should be `''''::varchar(50)` as you have doen.

Comment: Then try to concat query-string and `location_word_`, like this: `.. ILIKE ' || location_word_ || ' LIMIT ..`.

Comment: Or you can try to use double `%` in following string: `location_word_:=concat(location_word, '%%');`. [In addition to the format specifiers described above, the special sequence %% may be used to output a literal % character](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT).